# Sympy - Get constituent subsets from Union

Tags: python, set, sympy

Given a Union object (`sympy.sets.sets.Union`), how can I access the individual subsets that comprise the Union?

For example:

```
from sympy import Interval,Union

interval_1 = Interval.open(-5,-1)
interval_2 = Interval.open(1,5)

set_union = Union(interval_1, interval_2)
```

How can I get `interval_1` and `interval_2` from `set_union`?

Note: actually the Union object is constructed by `sympy.calculus.util.continuous_domain`, so I don't have direct access to the constituent intervals, only the Union object itself.

I can't find anything about this in the documentation. I tried iterating over the Union object but get a TypeError, "Not all constituent sets are iterable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `Union.args`:

```
>>> from sympy import Interval,Union
>>> 
>>> interval_1 = Interval.open(-5,-1)
>>> interval_2 = Interval.open(1,5)
>>> 
>>> set_union = Union(interval_1, interval_2)
>>> 
>>> for subset in set_union.args:
>>>     print(subset)
Interval.open(-5, -1)
Interval.open(1, 5)
```

Comment: `_argset` is private but you can use `.args` instead.